# Show one of the 3 views depandant on current user

Tags: groups, user, view

I have builded in Visual Studio (c#) a custom list, custom content type and 3 custom views. I am using sp 2010.

The list is working ok and I can see and select the 3 views. It is possible for the end user to change the view. I would like to disable this. I would like to use one of the 3 views depandant by current user.

For example:

if current user is member of the group "MyCustomGroup1" then show "view1".

else if current user is member of the group "MyCustomGroup2" then show "view2".

else show default view "view3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible(but not OOB) to set permissions on groups to access only certain view of list by default and luckily someone developed a solution for you too.

http://spviewpermission.codeplex.com/

Or you can do it using JavaScript too here's the link to [tutorial](http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/filter-list-view-based-on-membership-in-sharepoint-group/)

[Similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40042/can-i-manage-views-based-on-permissions-in-ootb-foundation-2010)

[Similar question 2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4443/is-setting-permissions-on-views-now-possible)

[SomeHow Similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35226/show-sharepointlist-content-based-on-query-string)

[Another Tutorial](http://www.estruyf.be/blog/sharepoint-2007-create-permissions-on-list-views/)

**Edit**

If you are using SharePoint 2010 you can use SharePoint designer to set view level permissions as demonstrated in this link.

[How to set view level permissions out of the box in SharePoint 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/433486/How-to-set-view-level-permissions-out-of-the-box-i)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I dont want to use 3th party stuff and also no javascript. I like the the solution in you last link (Similar question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40042/can-i-manage-views-based-on-permissions-in-ootb-foundation-2010). The only problem is that users which dont have permission to the page can see the link in the navigation bar, but got a 404 error. Is there some solution to not show the link in the left navigation menu?